# nhibernate, eager loading and paging

Tags: nhibernate, pagination, eager-loading

I am creating an mvc application that uses nhibernate and paging.  I have a parent > child relationship that I am trying to eager load my child records.  This is all working fine.

The problem I am having is with the paging.  I would like to have 15 items per page.  This works perfectly if each parent has only one child.  The problem is when a parent has more than 1 child.  For instance, if the parent has 2 child records,  then the database actually selects 15 records with two representing the same parent, one for each of the two children.  Therefore, in my data view on the page, it appears that there are only 14 records.

Does anyone know how I might go about getting my page counts by parent only while still eager loading my child entities?
This is going to be a public facing site, so I don't think it would be a good idea to lazy load since it will cause too many trips to the server.

Is there something built into NHibernate that might handle this that I am missing?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

You could mark your association property with `fetch="subselect"` - this also makes sure you don't run into problems with a huge cartesian product at the cost of making two queries for each select.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a distinct root entity result transformer on your query. You haven't said whether you're using HQL or Criteria, but the API is similar for both.

```
// criteria
criteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
```

This will force the result set to only contain distinct parent entities.

Comment: I am using the distinct root entity, but it is still counting the mulitple child items each time, not just counting the distinct parent items.

Comment: @James Gregory - Your suggestion won't work because paging is usually expressed as SELECT TOP(@p0) .... and in case there is eager loading you have joins which will make some entities appear far bellow limit imposed by TOP.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `batch-size` hint in your mapping for the child collection is probably the best/easiest way to deal with this. For further discussion, see my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096397/nhibernate-n1-fetch-problem/4100217#4100217).

Comment: In other words, instead of using eager-loading, this answer suggests to switch to lazy-loading with batching enabled on lazy loads for avoiding the N+1 performance issue.